# MySQL : Automatic column update with list of value

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys

I just want to update automatically a column of 2 tables linked with foreign keys.
To more, these columns have to contain not just one value, but a list of values.

Here is my example :

```
Table Name : members
Member name : Demo User
Assigned Tasks : <List of tasks assigned to "Demo User">

Table Name : tasks
Task Name : Modeling
Assigned To : <List of users assigned to "Modeling">
```

In each table, I want to be able to insert value in the column, and the other table is automatically updated.

Example :

```
Table Name : members
Member name : Demo User
Assigned Tasks : Modeling,Mapping

Table Name : tasks
Task Name : Modeling
Assigned To : AUTOMATIC UPDATE ->Demo User

Task Name : Mapping
Assigned To : AUTOMATIC UPDATE ->Demo User
```

I tried with foreign keys (using innoDB), but I just succeed to insert one value in the column, and the other table was not updated automatically...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Change your data model.  At the very least there is a one to many relationship between members and tasks (a member can have more than one task).  If a task can be assigned to more than one member, it's a many to many relationship.  If you don't know the normalized way to store that data, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I know what you mean, but don't you think create table for each member or task will create an giant database, which could become unstable ?

Comment: Creating a table for each member or task is not a normalized design either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never, ever store delimited values in a database. Normalize your data by creating a many-to-many table (in your case let's call it `assigned_tasks`) instead. It will pay off big time in a long run by enabling you to normally maintain and query your data.

That being said your schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE members
(
  member_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  member_name VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE tasks
(
  task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  task_name VARCHAR(32)
);
CREATE TABLE assigned_tasks
(
  member_id int, 
  task_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_id, task_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES members (member_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (task_id)   REFERENCES tasks (task_id)
);
```

Now if you need a representation with a delimited list of tasks per user you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY`

```sql
SELECT m.member_id, m.member_name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.task_name) tasks
  FROM assigned_tasks a JOIN members m
    ON a.member_id = m.member_id JOIN tasks t
    ON a.task_id = t.task_id
 GROUP BY m.member_id, m.member_name
```

Output:

```
| MEMBER_ID | MEMBER_NAME |            TASKS |
|-----------|-------------|------------------|
|         1 |   Demo User | Modeling,Mapping |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba087d/3)** demo

Comment: Thank you ! I understand better now. I succeed to have the result in the other side like that : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba087d/5 Thank you.

Comment: Depending on your business requirements, you may want to look at a variation of the assigned_tasks table.  If a member can be assigned a task for awhile, and then relieved of that task, and then re-assigned it, your data model has to be able to handle it.

Comment: Thank you again ! Now I created my "assigned" tables, I have 22 tables in my database. I think we can simplify that with just one table which will give me relationship between other tables ? Here's my database : http://pastebin.com/7KRnz3zj